# Windows Color System Calibration Loader (specified module could not be found 0x8007007E) - Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, color-profiles, nvidia

Background: Windows Color System Calibration Loader is used to automatically load Windows color profiles for your display once Windows is loaded. I'm planning to disable this so I can get Nvidia control panel to allow me to properly use Nvidia desktop color settings. Reason for that is so I can get the F.lux software to work properly when I take screenshots/snippets. Seems like this Calibration Loader doesn't work properly even after uninstalling F.lux. I am unable to use Windows Night Light as well so something is very wrong here.

Issue: Every time this task runs when I boot my computer, I get the following run result message shown in the Task Scheduler window: "The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)".

Running Windows 10 build 1909 and with Nvidia graphics drivers 445.87. Had F.lux installed but removed it temporarily.

I ran a System File Checker scan and it found no issues. Not too sure why Windows cannot find the Calibration Loader module and I'm not sure how to fix this issue.

Comment: You can disable f.lux when using specific apps, for example a screenshot program. You can also easily disable it temporarily.

Comment: Yep, I can disable it everytime but I found myself having to do that frequently where I turn it off and then turn it back on. Maybe there is a hotkey I can do to just do a workaround. It would be nice if I could solve the issue though but I guess if that may be too much work, your workaround would be good. Still need to figure out how to tell F.lux on how to disable itself when an app is in use or if I'm doing Windows print screen/snipping tool for example though

Comment: Windows 10 Calibrate Color Display is a one time execution. It does not run automatically. Do you have an app (Flux software) that is trying to run it?

Comment: I believe what you are referring to is different than the Task Scheduler Windows Color System Calibration Loader. I wasn't aware of this scheduled task until I saw this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ANMs5rnrfmA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to put a close to this and in case anyone else that might stumble upon this in the future...

I was able to resolve this issue after removing the Nvidia graphics drivers. Then I was able to make changes there and eventually fix Flux.